# whenever I install this app and grant permission for audio, my apps gets crashes

Tags: android

I made a music player app using min api level 30 and target api level 33, whenever I install this app and grant permission for audio, my apps gets crashes. It requires to open my app again and wait for 2-3 seconds to load my all music files and then app runs smoothly. How to fix this?

My app running log

```
01/17 13:48:09: Launching 'app' on vivo I2011.
Install successfully finished in 1 s 317 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.techxperts.iplay/com.techxperts.iplay.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 2891 on device 'vivo-i2011-3080325162000DU'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/echxperts.iplay: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/echxperts.iplay: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 210923482; UID 10335; state: ENABLED
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 171228096; UID 10335; state: ENABLED
I/AdrenoGLES-0: QUALCOMM build                   : 428fbbc7d8, I593c16c433
    Build Date                       : 09/27/21
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV************
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Reconstruct Branch               : 
I/AdrenoGLES-0: Build Config                     : S P 10.0.7 AArch64
I/AdrenoGLES-0: Driver Path                      : /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
I/AdrenoGLES-0: PFP: 0x016dd093, ME: 0x00000000
W/Parcel: Expecting binder but got null!
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: null receiver
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.vivo.framework.vperf.VivoScrollOptimizer.setMotionType(VivoScrollOptimizer.java:397)
W/System.err:     at com.vivo.framework.vperf.VivoPerfManager.setMotionType(VivoPerfManager.java:374)
W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer.setMotionEventInfo(Choreographer.java:391)
W/System.err:     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchMotionEventInfo(InputEventReceiver.java:307)
W/System.err:     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:339)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:176)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:324)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8464)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1059)
V/ImeFocusController: onWindowFocus: DecorView@e701846[MainActivity] softInputMode=STATE_UNSPECIFIED|ADJUST_RESIZE|IS_FORWARD_NAVIGATION
V/ImeFocusController: Restarting due to isRestartOnNextWindowFocus as true
D/ImeFocusController: onViewFocusChanged, view=DecorView@e701846[MainActivity], mServedView=null
V/ImeFocusController: checkFocus: view=null next=DecorView@e701846[MainActivity] force=true package=<none>
D/MediaPlayer: MediaPlayer create called
V/MediaPlayerNative: constructor
V/MediaPlayerNative: setListener
V/MediaPlayerNative: MediaPlayer::setParameter(1400)
V/MediaPlayerNative: MediaPlayer::setAudioSessionId(6865)
V/MediaPlayerNative: setDataSource(131, 0, 576460752303423487)
V/MediaPlayerNative: setVideoSurfaceTexture
V/MediaPlayerNative: prepare
V/MediaPlayerNative: message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerNative: MediaPlayer::notify() prepared
V/MediaPlayerNative: signal application thread
V/MediaPlayerNative: callback application
V/MediaPlayerNative: prepare complete - status=0
V/MediaPlayerNative: back from callback
V/MediaPlayerNative: invoke 76
D/MediaPlayer: MediaPlayer start called
V/MediaPlayerNative: start
D/MediaPlayer: MediaPlayer start end
W/Parcel: Expecting binder but got null!
V/MediaPlayerNative: invoke 76
V/MediaPlayerNative: message received msg=10000, ext1=1277, ext2=3
V/MediaPlayerNative: unrecognized message: (10000, 1277, 3)
V/MediaPlayerNative: callback application
V/MediaPlayerNative: back from callback
V/MediaPlayerNative: message received msg=10000, ext1=1277, ext2=3
V/MediaPlayerNative: unrecognized message: (10000, 1277, 3)
V/MediaPlayerNative: callback application
V/MediaPlayerNative: back from callback
V/MediaPlayerNative: message received msg=211, ext1=0, ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerNative: unrecognized message: (211, 0, 0)
V/MediaPlayerNative: callback application
V/MediaPlayerNative: back from callback
W/AidlConversion: aidl2legacy_AudioChannelLayout_audio_channel_mask_t: no legacy output audio_channel_mask_t found for AudioChannelLayout{layoutMask: 16}
W/AudioSystem-JNI: Unknown native audio format for JAVA API: 452984832
W/AudioSystem-JNI: Unknown native audio format for JAVA API: 469762048
W/AudioSystem-JNI: Unknown native audio format for JAVA API: 486539264
W/AudioSystem-JNI: Unknown native audio format for JAVA API: 117440512
W/AudioSystem-JNI: Unknown native audio format for JAVA API: 503316482
W/AudioSystem-JNI: Unknown native audio format for JAVA API: 503316496
W/AudioSystem-JNI: Unknown native audio format for JAVA API: 503316736
W/AidlConversion: aidl2legacy_AudioChannelLayout_audio_channel_mask_t: no legacy output audio_channel_mask_t found for AudioChannelLayout{layoutMask: 16}
W/AudioSystem-JNI: Unknown native audio format for JAVA API: 452984832
W/AudioSystem-JNI: Unknown native audio format for JAVA API: 469762048
W/AudioSystem-JNI: Unknown native audio format for JAVA API: 486539264
W/AudioSystem-JNI: Unknown native audio format for JAVA API: 117440512
W/AudioSystem-JNI: Unknown native audio format for JAVA API: 503316482
W/AudioSystem-JNI: Unknown native audio format for JAVA API: 503316496
W/AudioSystem-JNI: Unknown native audio format for JAVA API: 503316736
V/ImeFocusController: onWindowFocus: DecorView@44027e5[PlaySong] softInputMode=STATE_UNSPECIFIED|ADJUST_PAN|IS_FORWARD_NAVIGATION
D/ImeFocusController: onViewFocusChanged, view=DecorView@44027e5[PlaySong], mServedView=null
V/ImeFocusController: checkFocus: view=null next=DecorView@44027e5[PlaySong] force=false package=<none>
V/MediaPlayerNative: message received msg=211, ext1=0, ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerNative: unrecognized message: (211, 0, 0)
V/MediaPlayerNative: callback application
V/MediaPlayerNative: back from callback
I/echxperts.iplay: Compiler allocated 5501KB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xb400007976d8eed0 (ListView) with handle 0xb400007886dee040
W/System.err: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.vivo.framework.vperf.VivoScrollOptimizer.setMotionType(VivoScrollOptimizer.java:397)
W/System.err:     at com.vivo.framework.vperf.VivoPerfManager.setMotionType(VivoPerfManager.java:374)
W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer.setMotionEventInfo(Choreographer.java:391)
W/System.err:     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchMotionEventInfo(InputEventReceiver.java:307)
W/System.err:     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:339)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:176)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:324)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8464)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1059)
W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Surface has already been released.
W/System.err:     at android.view.Surface.checkNotReleasedLocked(Surface.java:778)
W/System.err:     at android.view.Surface.setFlingType(Surface.java:801)
W/System.err:   ... 13 more
V/MediaPlayerNative: pause
V/MediaPlayerNative: message received msg=7, ext1=0, ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerNative: unrecognized message: (7, 0, 0)
V/MediaPlayerNative: callback application
V/MediaPlayerNative: back from callback
D/MTP: onPaused: true
D/MTP: onSeekComplete at 4226000
V/MediaPlayerNative: message received msg=211, ext1=0, ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerNative: unrecognized message: (211, 0, 0)
V/MediaPlayerNative: callback application
V/MediaPlayerNative: back from callback
W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
V/MediaPlayerNative: message received msg=211, ext1=0, ext2=0
V/MediaPlayerNative: unrecognized message: (211, 0, 0)
V/MediaPlayerNative: callback application
V/MediaPlayerNative: back from callback
```

my MainActivity.java

```html
package com.techxperts.iplay;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ListView listView;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        Dexter.withContext(this)
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {

                 //       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ArrayList<File> mySongs = fetchSongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
                        String[] items = new String[mySongs.size()];
                        for(int i=0; i<mySongs.size(); i++){
                            items[i] = mySongs.get(i).getName().replace(".mp3", "");
                        }

                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlaySong.class);
                                String currentSong = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                                intent.putExtra("songList", mySongs);
                                intent.putExtra("currentSong", currentSong);
                                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                        permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                })
                .check();
    }
    public ArrayList<File> fetchSongs(File file){
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
        File [] songs = file.listFiles();
        if(songs !=null){
            for(File myFile: songs){
                if(!myFile.isHidden() && myFile.isDirectory()){
                    arrayList.addAll(fetchSongs(myFile));
                }
                else{
                    if(myFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3") && !myFile.getName().startsWith(".")){
                        arrayList.add(myFile);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return arrayList;
    }

}
```

Any solution for this error?

Comment: Show how you request permission for audio to begin with. Post the code. And you have a NullPointerException which you did not mention.

Comment: @blackapps I edited my  post and mentioned my codes please check it

Comment: Ok. Now tell us which statement causes that exception. If you do not know then first remove all code from onCreate (you can comment it out) and then add code line for line until you know.

Comment: Okk I'll check and inform you soon.